# Custom Isabelle syntax breaks existing syntax

Tags: syntax, isabelle

I am attempting to generate a nice syntax for mapping a function over the values of an associative list, i.e. I want to write `[x ↦ f y | (x ↦ y) ∈ l]` for `mapAList f l`. I came up with

```
syntax
 "_alist_map" :: "['b, pttrn, ('a × 'b) list] ⇒ ('a × 'b) list"
 ("[x ↦ _ | '(x ↦ _') ∈ _]")
```

which works, but causes `term "(x,y)#[]"` to tell me `Inner syntax error at "(x , y ) # []"` and the `(x` is shaded slightly different.

The reason seems that once `x` appears in a mixfix annotation, it now always a literal token to the grammer (a *delimiter* according to §7.4.1 of isar-ref) and no longer an identifier – just like the syntax for `if ... then ... else ...` prevents `if` from being a variable name

Can I somehow work around this problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does `mapAList` only map `f` over the *values* of `l` (i.e., the 2nd components of pairs)? It seems that the syntax is more cumbersome to type than just writing the function application ;) Do you have an example where readability is actually improved (I'm aware that this is highly subjective).

Comment: The function `f` in my application is written with special sytnax itself, i.e. `[| x |]`, and `map (λx. [| x |])` is not as readable as `[x ↦ [| y |] | (x ↦ y) ∈ l]`

Answer (score 2):

Identifier names used in mixfix annotations cannot be used as identifiers any longer, and I don't know any way around that. Therefore, instead of using `x` as a variable name, you can pick a non-identifier symbol like `\<xX>` or `\<mapAListvariable>` and setup the LaTeX output to print this as `x` by adding `\newcommand{\isasymmapAListvariable}{x}` to your `root.tex`.

You can also add `\<xX>` or `\<mapAListvariable>` to the symbols file of Isabelle/JEdit (preferably in `$ISABELLE_HOME_USER/etc/symbols`) and assign it some Unicode point that will be used for display in Isabelle/JEdit.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a small experiment with a function `map_alist` that hopefully corresponds to your `mapAList` and which is defined as follows:

```
fun map_alist :: "('b ⇒ 'c) ⇒ ('a × 'b) list ⇒ ('a × 'c) list"
where
  "map_alist f [] = []" |
  "map_alist f ((x, y) # xs) = (x, f y) # map_alist f xs"
```

Then existing syntax can be used which looks a little bit as you intended. Maybe this is an option?

```
lemma "map_alist f xs = [(x, f y). (x, y) ← xs]"
  by (induct xs) auto
```

Comment: Close, but how do I make Isabelle print the nice syntax when I use `thm` or antiquotations in my document setup?